# Python: Output prefixed with b

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python so please bear with me here!

I've taken some code from [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362715-dbf-reader-and-writer/) (and then butchered it around a bit) to open a DBF file and then output to CSV.

This worked perfectly well on Python 2.5 but I've now moved it to Python 3.3 and ran into a number of issues, most of which I've resolved.

The final issue I have is that in order to run the code, I've had to prefix some items with `b` (because I was getting `TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object` errors)

The code now works, and outputs correctly, except that every field is displayed as `b'DATAHERE'` (where DATAHERE is the actual data of course!)

So... does anyone know how I can stop it from outputting the `b` character? I can post code if required but it's fairly lengthy so I was hoping someone would be able to spot what I expect to be something simple that I've done wrong!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the code output byte values; if you expected unicode strings instead, simply decode:

```
yourdata.decode('ascii')
```

where `ascii` should be replaced by the encoding your data uses.

Comment: Thanks - as per my comment on zhangyangyu's answer - how would I include this function in `records = [[rec[7].replace(b' ', b'')] + [rec[9].strip()] + [rec[10].strip()] + [rec[11].strip()] + [rec[3].strip()] for rec in records]`?

Comment: You then have a a nested list of byte strings; `[r.decode('someenc') for r in your_new_list]` decodes each in turn; you can chain the `.decode()` calls right after the `.strip()` or `.replace()` calls.